# Wifi issue in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: wireless, 16.04

Laptop connected to wifi network. Connection established. But web page not loading.

Able to connect and browse using Ethernet cable.

Comment: can you give the output of this       sudo lshw -class network

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.